# Struts : for each loop

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl, struts-1

I am trying to use `foreach` loop in `Select` tag.

```
<html:select property="year" >

   <s:iterator var="i" begin="${1}" end="${monthlyChargeForm.currentYear - 2000}" >
            <s:set var="counter" value="${monthlyChargeForm.currentYear}"/>
                 <html:option  value="${counter}">
                        <c:out value="${counter}"/>                  
                 </html:option>
            <s:set var="counter" value="${counter-1}"/>
     </s:iterator>
</html:select>
```

I am trying to list all the years from current year to YEAR : 2000 in the drop down.
But I am getting empty drop-down.

Action class code : I've used

```
// monthlyChargeForm.setCurrentYear(now.get(Calendar.YEAR) );
```

to get the current year.

```
public class MonthlyChargeAction extends Action {

 private ActionMessages messages;

 public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,  
                             HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)        
   throws Exception {
    ServletContext context = getServlet().getServletContext();
    BACUtils bacUtils = new  BACUtils();
    String sessionStatus = HtmlBean.isSessionOut(request.getSession(false), context);
    if(!Constants.SUCCESS_STATUS.equals(sessionStatus)) {
        return mapping.findForward("sessionOut");
    }
    String accesssStatus = HtmlBean.isSessionValid(request.getSession(false), context,  
                                                  Properties.ACCESS_PROFILE[8][0]);
    if(!Constants.SUCCESS_STATUS.equals(accesssStatus)) {
        return mapping.findForward("sessionOut");
    }
    MonthlyChargeForm monthlyChargeForm = (MonthlyChargeForm)form;
    Reports reports = new  Reports();
    String sUser =(String) request.getSession().getAttribute("USERID");
    String returnVal = "";
    int i = 0;
    try {
            monthlyChargeForm.setFromDate(bacUtils.getDate());
            monthlyChargeForm.setToDate(bacUtils.getDate());


            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

            String fromDate = monthlyChargeForm.getFromDate();
            String toDate = monthlyChargeForm.getToDate();
            String curentDate = bacUtils.getDate();

            monthlyChargeForm.setCurrentYear(now.get(Calendar.YEAR) );

            System.out.println("Current Year :::::::::" +  

                                                 monthlyChargeForm.getCurrentYear());

            AuditTrial.insertLog(5,sUser,null,"General Reports Module Loaded 
                                                        Successfully",(String) 
  request.getSession().getAttribute("OPER_TYPE"),"S",request.getRemoteAddr(),context);
            if(monthlyChargeForm.getPageIndex() == null ||
                    monthlyChargeForm.getPageIndex().trim().length() == 0)
                    monthlyChargeForm.setPageIndex(Integer.toString(BACUtils.getIntVal(
                            monthlyChargeForm.getPageIndex())));

                     if(monthlyChargeForm.getMonth()!=null &&        
                                            monthlyChargeForm.getYear()!=null )
                     {
                monthlyChargeForm.setMonthlyChargeReport(
                        reports.getMonthlyChargeData(monthlyChargeForm, 10, context));
                     }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Constants.SUCCESS_MAPPING);
    return mapping.findForward(Constants.SUCCESS_MAPPING);
   }
```

Comment: Please share your Action class code...

Comment: Which version of Struts are you using? Struts2 doesn't have `html` namespace, Struts1 doesn't have `s` namespace.

Comment: action class code is used.

Comment: Does the action have a form bean?

Comment: @user2761566 It looks like you're randomly mixing tag libraries from S1 and S2. Use only Struts 1 tags since you're using Struts 1.

Comment: @RomanC Tag library namespaces are arbitrary, and chosen by the user. Convention uses what you state, though; `html` for S1 HTML tags, `s` for the default S2 framework tags.

Comment: @DaveNewton Convention is invaluable part of the Java, especially if it concern naming. They are arbitrary ofcourse, but I didn't see the code from Apache where prefix was other than html for html taglib. And this taglib made a revolution in JSP. It was a pre-EL era.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use foreach loop then you can try `forEach` tag from JSTL core taglib.

```
<html:select property="year" >
   <c:forEach varStatus="i" begin="${monthlyChargeForm.currentYear}" end="2000" step="-1">
     <html:option  value="${i.index}">
       <c:out value="${i.index}"/>                  
     </html:option>
   </c:forEach>
</html:select>
```